# How to set multiple states using one response from axios API call in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-effect, use-state

I invoke a **GET** API using axios in React. Backend (Python-Flask) is returning data by writing `return jsonify(animals=animals, cars=cars)` and these (cars and animals) are arrays.

The response has data in the following format:

```json
{
  "animals": ["elephant", "lion", "dog"],
  "cars": ["range rover", "fortuner", "land cruiser"]
}
```

I want to update the `cars` state using the `cars` array and the `animals` state using the `animals` array. I tried the following but only animals state is updating, cars state is remaining empty

**App**

```
export default function App() {
    const [animals, setAnimals] = useState([])
    const [cars, setCars] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=> {
        axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/animals_cars").then(
            response=> setAnimals(response.data.animals),
            resp => setCars(resp.data.cars)
        );
        console.log(cars)
        console.log(animals)
    }, []);
}
```

Any help on the responses, that is where I have no idea how can I split the response to update different states.

Answer (score 2):

[`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) takes up to two arguments; callback functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise. In this case, your second callback (`resp => setCars(resp.data.cars)`) is only called if the Promise is rejected.

You want to use the first callback which is called if the Promise is fulfilled. You can update two state variables in one single function like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [animals, setAnimals] = useState([]);
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/animals_cars')
    .then((response) => {
      setCars(response.data.animals);
      setAnimals(response.data.cars);
    });
    // state updates are asynchronous
    // state is not updated yet, you can't log these
    // well, you can but chances are it's the default value []
    console.log(cars);
    console.log(animals);
  }, []);
}
```

Please note though that `useState` is asynchronous. You can't update the state on one line and assume it's already changed on the next one. You'll likely log the unchanged state.

Answer (score 2):

You need an async function when you are loading data from an API to wait for the completion of the function. To do that in a useEffect you need to define a new function and execute it only when a condition is met. In this case I create a new boolean constant **loading**, I check against it's value and if it's true I execute the **load** function. Upon completion of the function I set loading to false and that would prevent the load function from executing again. This has the advantage that if you want to fetch your data again all you have to do is to set loading to true.

Another way to do that is to define a memoised load function with useCallback outside of the useEffect but I don't want to complicate things for you.

A clean way to write that is the following.

```
export default function App() {
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
        const [animals, setAnimals] = useState([])
        const [cars, setCars] = useState([])
    
        useEffect(()=> {
            const load = async () => {
                const responseData = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/animals_cars")
                .then((response) => {
                  return response.data;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.log(error);
                });
                setAnimals(responseData.animals);
                setCars(responseData.cars);
                setLoading(false);
             }
            if (loading) {
                load();
            }
        },[loading]);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, as I explain in my answer having this `loading` state variable is very helpful if you want to trigger a reload, e.g. if you have dynamic parameters for your fetch endpoint, when the user updates them you simply set `loading` to true and the load executes again.

Answer (score 0):

You Can hadle that with function like this

useEffect(() => {
axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/animals_cars")

.then(function (response) {
// handle success

```
    setAnimals(response.data.animals);
    setCars(response.data.cars);
  });
console.log(cars);
console.log(animals);
```

}, []);